# How to initialize the bits in a register using C in a readable manner

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a 24 bit register that comprises a number of fields. For example, the 3 upper bits are "mode", the bottom 10 bits are "data rate divisor", etc. Now, I can just work out what has to go into this 24 bits and code it as a single hex number 0xNNNNNN. However, that is fairly unreadable to anyone trying to maintain it.

The question is, if I define each subfield separately what's the best way of coding it all together?

Comment: You can initialise it to a number of int's with say {3,0,0,1} for mode 3 divisor 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic way is to use the `<<` left shift operator on constant values and combine all values with either `+` or `|`.  For example:

```
*register_address = (SYNC_MODE << 21) | ... | DEFAULT_RATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

The "standard" approach for this problem is to use a `struct` with [`bitfield`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) members. Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int divisor: 10;
    unsigned int field1: 9;
    char field2: 2;
    unsigned char mode: 3;
} fields;
```

The numbers after each field name specify the number of bits used by that member. In the example above, field `divisor` uses 10 bits and can store values between `-512` and `511` (signed integer) while `mode` can store unsigned values on 3 bits: between `0` and `7`.

The range of values for each field use the usual rules regarding signed/unsigned and but the field length (char/int/long) is limited to the specified number of bits. Of course, a `char` can still hold up to 8 bits, a `short` up to 16 a.s.o. The coercion rules are the usual rules for the types of the fields, taking into account their size (i.e. storing `-5` in `mode` will convert it to `unsigned` (and the actual value will probably be `3`).

There are several issues you need to pay attention of (some of them are also mentioned in the **Notes** section of the documentation page about [`bit fields`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field):

- the total amount of bits declared in the structure must be 24 (the size of your register);
- because your structure uses 3 bytes, it's possible that some positions in arrays of such structures to behave strange because they span the allocation unit size (which is usually 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the hardware);
- the order of the bit fields in the allocation unit is not guaranteed by the standard; depending on the architecture, it's possible that in the final 3-bytes pack, the field `mode` contains either the most significant 3 bits or the least significant 3 bites; you can sort this thing out easily, though.

You probably need to handle the values you store in a `fields` structure all at once. For that you can embed the structure in an union:

```
typedef union {
   fields f;
   unsigned int a;
} reg;

reg x;
/* Access individual fields */
x.f.mode = 2;
x.f.divisor = 42;
/* Get the entire register */
printf("%06X\n", x.a);
```

#### Solution 2

An alternative way to do (kind of) the same thing is to use macros to extract the fields and to compose the entire register:

```
#define MAKE_REG(mode, field2, field1, divisor) \
         ((((mode) & 0x07) << 21) | \
         (((field2) & 0x03) << 19) | \
         (((field1) & 0x01FF) << 10 )| \
         ((divisor) & 0x03FF))

#define GET_MODE(reg) (((reg) & 0xE00000) >> 21)
#define GET_FIELD2(reg) (((reg) & 0x180000) >> 19)
#define GET_FIELD1(reg) (((reg) & 0x07FC00) >> 10)
#define GET_DIVISOR(reg) ((reg) & 0x0003FF)
```

The first macro assembles the `mode`, `field2`, `field1`, `divisor` values into a 3-bytes integer. The other set of macros extract the values of individual fields. All of them assume the processed numbers are unsigned.

#### Pros and cons

The `struct` (embedded in an `union`) solution:

- `[+]` it allows the compiler to do some checks of the values you want to put into the fields (and issue warnings); also, it does the correct conversions between signed and unsigned;

The macro solution:

- `[+]` it is not sensible to memory alignment issues, you put the bits exactly where you want;
- `(-)` it doesn't check the range of the values you put in fields;
- `(-)` the handling of signed values is a little bit trickier using macros; the macros suggested here work only for unsigned values; more shifting is required in order to use signed values.